# OpenSSL Wrong Host Name

Tags: ssl, openssl

I use site badssl.com in order to check whether I am able to catch all invalid certificates. One of the sites with invalid certificate is https://wrong.host.badssl.com/. Nevertheless if I type in cmd `openssl s_client -connect wrong.host.badssl.com:443`, I receive verification OK status. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Also if not using a recent OpenSSL version, you need to add `-servername` otherwise SNI won't happen properly and you can connect to another host than the one expected. Other than that, your question is offtopic here as not related to software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I solve the problem?

Newer versions of openssl have the option `-verify_hostname`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect wrong.host.badssl.com:443 \
   -verify_hostname wrong.host.badssl.com
...
    Verify return code: 62 (Hostname mismatch)
```

Older versions don't have this option and there is no way to enable the functionality in this older versions otherwise.